# Overlapping Border on Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place a black border below the dropdown menu, then having the "selected" page which is currently the "Home" page being underlined using a orange border. I am trying to overlap the orange border on the black border.

http://jsfiddle.net/46z5su4u/

Edited
Some people seems to be confused, I want to put the orange line on top of the black line.
http://jsfiddle.net/46z5su4u/2/

Any advices?

HTML:

```
<h1>Drop Down Menu</h1>
<header>
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>
  <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sub Menu 2 THIS IS SO LONG IT MIGHT CAUSE AN ISSEUE BUT MAYBE NOT?</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header
{
    border-bottom:4px solid #3a3a3a;
}

#primary_nav_wrap
{
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-bottom:-4px;
    position:relative;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height:32px;
    padding:0 15px;
    font-family:"Open Sans","Lucida Grande",Tahoma,"Trebuchet MS",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:1.1em;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
    border-bottom:4px solid #ff7500;
    font-weight:700;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item a
{
    color:#333;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li a:hover
{
    color: #ff7500;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    background:#f8f8f8;
    padding: 0 12px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #ccc;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
    float:none;
    width:150px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
    border-top: solid 1px #fff;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li:after
{
    content: "";
}

nav ul ul li:last-child a
{
    border-bottom: none;
}

nav ul ul li:first-child a
{
    border-top: none;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
    line-height:120%;
    padding:10px 6px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: You mean like this? - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ylzsp

Comment: Yes, something like that, but I want that black line to stretch all the way across page.

Comment: Check it out now...same codepen..updated

Comment: that broke the dropdown menu display ._.

Answer (score 0):

you may need a lower boarder when you move?

```
#primary_nav_wrap ul li a:hover
{
  color: #ff7500;
  border-top: 4px solid #ff7500;/*add*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/46z5su4u/1/

this is all i have added

```
#primary_nav_wrap ul li ul li {
border-bottom:1px solid orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bfgvo

Added to html

```
<div class="clearBoth"></div>
<div id="top_blackline"></div>
```

Added to css

```
.clearBoth
{
    clear:both;
}

#top_blackline
{
    margin-top:-4px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom:4px solid #3a3a3a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the dark border on the first-level `<li>s` instead of `<header>`.
So the updated `css` code will look like this:

```
header {
    position: absolute; /* removed border */
}

/* add the following rule */

#primary_nav_wrap > ul > li {
    border-bottom:4px solid #3a3a3a;
}
```

which sets the dark border on first-level `<li>s` only using the direct child selector `>`, more on this selector [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors).

a preview of the code above is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/46z5su4u/6/).